# Too many CSP Whitelist headers

Tags: magento2, apache2, csp, http-header

I am getting errors on CSP_Whitelist headers in an apache2.4 environment.
Apparently, there are too many of them, And I can't say which ones are more important than others.

Is there a way to determine which headers are used, which are important, and which can be ignored or are already handled in another way?

Also, Is there a difference in handling these headers when code 'lives' in app/code/ or in vendor map?